# Weird error message at bottom of newsletter

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter, the-overflow

The bottom of today's newsletter looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

(The dark colours come from a browser extension.)

Copied text:

> Fuze
>
> calling...
>
> Can't complete call
> We're sorry about that. Please try again or contact support if you continue to have issues.
> [Cancel][Retry]

That's not only weird, but also a bit suspicious. I have not tried clicking those buttons and I also don't want to. Why is that there? Is it supposed to be a weird joke?

Comment: is that how it looks in GMail? GMail cuts off lengthy emails and if that happens in the middle of html markup you end-up with weird stuff.

Comment: There is no "show full mail" button (which is surprising, because it often appears even on short mails that are already fully displayed).

Comment: I just noticed the highlighting on "New". That actually comes from a GMail bug. I opened this mail from an inverted search, but it still highlights the words that are in the excluded phrase. I searched for `-subject="New questions in"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for noting this. Looked into it and it seems it was a syntax issue in the newsletter. This has been fixed and you shouldn't see it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of research; I literally just searched "Fuze and Stack Exchange" and the third result for me was [image: Third result of "fuze stack exchange search" on google]

There may have been a recent collaboration with Fuze - a systems integrator - that may have had unintended consequences given that it somehow extended to e-mails. Personally I would have just copied the link to a Tor Browser tab and clicked the buttons just to see what would happen. But that's just me. If it really bothers you I would suggest reporting this on the [Stack Exchange Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues) issue page but I suspect it won't be a problem for you so much as it is SE's and Fuze's as it could be exposing some inner workings that we aren't supposed to see.